# Forcing links loaded with Ajax to open in a new tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, external-links

I am using this script to force links to Open in a new Window with Jquery, and it works fine

```
// add external links
function addExternalLinks () { 

$("a[href*='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname.replace
       ("www.","")+"']), a.linkException").each(function() {
   if($(this).find('img ').length == 0) {
$(this).click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        }).addClass('externalLink').attr("title", $(this).attr("title")+" - ( This link will open in a new window )");   

        }
   });
}
```

HOWEVER, part of the page is using content loaded from an external HTML page, using LOAD.

```
function showInfo( info ) {
$("#layerinfo").load("descriptions.html #" + info );
};
```

I want the links contained within this loaded content to also be forced to open in a new widow with the same script.
I cannot get it to work properly.

Something like :-

```
function showInfo( info ) {
var infoContent = "descriptions.html #" + info;

$("#layerinfo").load(infoContent,function(){
$("#layerinfo").html().addExternalLinks();
}); 
};
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addExternalLinks` is just a function, not a method of String (which is what `.html` returns) nor is it a jQuery method to be chained.

```
$("#layerinfo").load(infoContent, function () {
    addExternalLinks();
});
```

By the way, for `addExternalLinks` couldn't you just add `.attr("target", "_blank")` to said links instead of using a click event?

Comment: It work locally, but when I upload to a server, the external links do not work on the loaded content . Any ideas ? I adapted the function as per your sugestion :-

Comment: // add external links
function addExternalLinks () { 

$("a[href*='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname.replace
           ("www.","")+"']), a.linkException").each(function() {
       if($(this).find('img ').length == 0) {
$(this).attr("target", "_blank").addClass('externalLink').attr("title", $(this).attr("title")+" - ( This link will open in a new window )");
        
        }
   });
}

Answer (score 1):

try to add attr instead:

```
$(this).attr("target", "_blank");
```

hope this help!